# Open databases from SQL Server like you do it with MySQL with PhpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a backup from a data base (SQL Server), i never worked with this type (always with MySQL and PhpMyAdmin to see the data). How can i see the data who is inside the backup? there is a Microsoft program to do that? like access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SQL Server Management Studio, you use **Restore** feature.  [The process is laid out in the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx)

Obviously, you restore to another SQL Server database instance.  The version of the instance can be newer than the version the backup came from - the compatibility level will just be set accordingly.

Comment: If you're trying to do this on your local computer instead of another server, download MS SQL Server Express and you'll get the Management Studio and a local SQL Server. http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/

Answer (score 0):

depends whether you want to pay for the solution ;)
If you have the disk space and don't want to pay then you have to restore the backup.

If you dont have the disk space, and/or don't mind paying and/or you only want to restore a certain subset of the data you can use quest software's litespeed http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server